# Expect script not recognizing "--MORE--", not running any commands after that

Tags: installation, expect

I am writing an expect script to automate a Sophos install.  Here's what it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set installdir [lindex $argv 0]
set timeout 20

spawn "./install.sh"

expect {
    sleep 5
    "Press <return> to display Licence. Then press <spc> to scroll forward." {send "\r"}
    -ex "--More--" {send -- " "; exp_continue}
    "Do you accept the licence? Yes(Y)/No(N)\\\[N\\\]" {send "Y"}
    "Where do you want to install Sophos Anti-Virus? \\\[/opt/sophos-av\\\]" {"send $installdir/sophos-av"}
    "Do you want to enable on-access scanning? Yes(Y)/No(N) \\\[Y\\\]" {"send \r"}
    "Do you want to enable remote management? Yes(Y)/No(N) \\\[Y\\\]" {"send \r"}
    "Username for Sophos Anti-Virus GUI? \\\[admin\\\]" {"send \r"}
    "Password for Sophos Anti-Virus GUI?" {"********"}
    "Re-enter the same password." {"********"}
}

interact
```

When I run the expect script, it enters the keystroke for the License, but does nothing when the first "--MORE--" prompt comes up, and runs no subsequent commands.  Thoughts?  Ideas?

Comment: That `sleep 5` is not a sleep command: expect will look for the pattern `sleep` and if found execute the command `5`. If you actually want to sleep, put the command above the expect command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting the program to see each one of those patterns in turn? If so you need to use multiple, sequential expect and send commands:

```
sleep 5
expect "Press <return> to display Licence. Then press <spc> to scroll forward." 
send "\r"
expect {
    -ex "--More--" {send -- " "; exp_continue}
    "Do you accept the licence? Yes(Y)/No(N)\\\[N\\\]" 
}
send "Y"
expect "Where do you want to install Sophos Anti-Virus? \\\[/opt/sophos-av\\\]" 
send "$installdir/sophos-av\r"
expect "Do you want to enable on-access scanning? Yes(Y)/No(N) \\\[Y\\\]" 
send "\r"
expect "Do you want to enable remote management? Yes(Y)/No(N) \\\[Y\\\]" 
send "\r"
expect "Username for Sophos Anti-Virus GUI? \\\[admin\\\]" 
send "\r"
expect "Password for Sophos Anti-Virus GUI?" 
send "********\r"
expect "Re-enter the same password." 
send "********\r"
interact
```

Once `expect` executes an "action" block, the expect command will return. It won't hang around waiting to match other patterns unless you tell it to (`exp_continue`)

Helpful tip: while developing an expect script, turn on verbose debugging output: `exp_internal 1` near the top of the script.

Comment: So I tried the above, and it certainly reacts correctly to --MORE--, but it never moves onto the next command.

Comment: Of course (in hindsight). `expect` need to await something else to break out of the "more" loop. Updated.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what I'm seeing.  Here is a small example: 

expect: does "\u001b[27m\r*\u001b[K\r\n* The licence and distribution terms for any publically available version or\r\n* derivative of this code cannot be changed.  i.e. this code cannot simply be\r\n* copied and put under another distribution licence\r\n* [including the GNU Public Licence.]\r\n*/\r\n\r\nDo you accept the licence? Yes(Y)/No(N) [N]\r\n> " (spawn_id exp4) match exact string "--More--"? no
"sleep"? no
"Do you accept the licence? Yes(Y)/No(N)\[N\]"? no`

Comment: It looks like it starts expecting the license line before the exp_continue loop should finish.

Comment: expect by default does glob-style matching. You're asking to match an exact string when you want to match if that string is a substring. Add globbing wildcards: `*Do you accept the licence?*`